# SQL Server - Error: converting charcter string in "uniqueidentifier"

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I am new to SQL Server and am trying to implement the steps from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElGSvn3OCK4 (At around minute 12).

I want to implement a semantic search. Therefore I want to set a Search Property List. Here is the code (which is from the tutorial):

```
ALTER SEARCH PROPERTY LIST DocumentPropertiesTest
ADD 'Title'
WITH (PROPERTY_SET_GUID = 'F29F85E0-1068-AB91-08002B27B309', PROPERTY_INT_ID = 2,
PROPERTY_DESCRIPTION = 'System.Title = Title of the item' );
GO
```

I am getting an error that says that the conversion in uniqueidentifier failed. Can anyone explain what this means in this example? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A UNIQUEIDENTIFIER field must have a valid GUID

Your string `'F29F85E0-1068-AB91-08002B27B309'` isn't a GUID.
You can use something like [this](http://guid.us/Test/GUID) to validate.
A GUID has another 4 digit block that you seem to be missing.
For example:
`'F29F85E0-1068-0000-AB91-08002B27B309'` note the `0000` around the middle.